# Multi-threading necessary here : More students submitting their response to store in database

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, servlets

I am developing student response system. In my application multiple students (more that 500) at the same time taking quiz and submitting their response through servlet.

### Take quiz :

Global Object contain the quiz details(questions, options), All the students send the request to servlet to collect quiz data.

### Submitting Response :

Student currently submitting response through servlet, it will collect the response(Json) and store in Database.

In this above scenarios  i have not used multi-threading. Is it necessary to use Multi-threading here?

If i convert the code with multi-threading will it make the program more effective?

What if, I am using RESTful API to collect data and storing that data in a class instead Servlet? ( Instead of using servlet if all the student submitting the response through REST technology. Will REST API technology himself handle multi-threading like servlet ?)

Comment: You probably *don't* need to take care of multithreading. The servlet container will provide threads and distribute the workload across them. You *might* have to look at synchronization, but only *if* some object can possibly be modified (written to) concurrently by different threads of the server.

Comment: If your pages respond in 20 ms, this means 50 students could respond every second or 500 students every 10 seconds with one thread.  BTW Most likely your web server is already multi-threaded.

Comment: As I am using servlet its handling multi-threading. If i used the REST to collect the response for all the students and store the response in database in a class. Will it handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a servlet, that servlet executes in a servlet container (like Tomcat, for instance). Tomcat manages the threads for you, for each HTTP request Tomcat takes a thread from its pool and runs the request on that. So your servlet is already using multithreading.

There may be things you can do to improve the program. If you're not using a connection pool then using one would be a big improvement. Without the connection pool the threads all have to take turns accessing the same connection, with the pool more work can get done concurrently. (In addition using a connection pool makes the application more tolerant of network hiccups and database availability problems.)

Also make sure your servlet is not keeping any state and doesn't have synchronized methods. If there's user information that needs to be held onto, keep it in the HTTP session.

These steps are about minimizing the cases where your threads are blocked waiting for a lock held by another thread, so that your multiple threads do more work and less waiting.

Remember REST is an architectural style, not a framework. You don't say what specific framework you're intending to use, but it would seem unlikely to me that a framework's designers would want to make decisions that undermined the concurrency of applications that used the framework. It's a lot more likely that your concurrency would be limited by not pooling connections and using too much synchronization.

Comment: As I am using servlet its handling multi-threading. If i used the REST to collect the response for all the students and store the response in database in a class. Will it handle this situation?

Comment: @Rajavel: not sure what you mean. i'd expect the students' responses would get saved to a database and you could query that database to get the responses for all the students.

Comment: By the way at the same time all the student submitte the response (Json to a REST) how that situation RESTful will hand?

Comment: @Rajavel: sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now forgot the servlet. Instead of using servlet if all the student submitting the response through REST technology. Will rest himself handle multi-threading like servlet ?

Comment: @Rajavel: in a web application there's always a servlet. It's just that frameworks may provide one and encapsulate it so that you don't deal with it yourself. i don't know what REST framework you're using (there are several), you'd need to try it out to see how it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70241/discussion-between-rajavel-d-and-nathan-hughes).